# Checkbox array inside foreach form. Associate each checkbox with another variable

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach, key-value

For the below example everything works as expected when ALL the checkboxes are checked. The problem occurs when one or more (but NOT all of them) are checked.

```
<form action="someaction" method="post">
 <?php foreach ($fields as $field) { ?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkpid[]" value="<?php echo $field['pid']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="checkprice[]" value="<?php echo $field['price']; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 <?php } ?>
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['checkpid'])) { ?>
 <?php
  $checkpid = $_POST['checkpid'];
  $checkprice = $_POST['checkprice'];
 ?>

  <?php foreach ($checkpid as $key => $checkpid) { ?>
   <?php
    $eachpid[] = $checkpid.",".$checkprice[$key];    
   ?>
  <?php } ?>

   <?php print_r($eachpid), ?> // the $checkpid is always as expected, but the $checkprice does not match its row.
<?php } ?>
```

With my little knowledge I suspect it is something wrong in the declaration of the $key, but I am overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is all i can suggest.

instead of adding two input how about adding the two data in value of a checkbox input separated with |. then when submitted just explode the value and receive array 1 for id and 1 for price.

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['checkp'])) { 

    $checkp = $_POST['checkp'];
    foreach ($checkp as $check) { 
      $c = explode("|", $check);
      $eachpid[] = $c[0].",".$c[1];    
    }

    print_r($eachpid);
  } 
?>

<form action="" method="post">
 <?php foreach ($fields as $field) { ?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkp[]" value="<?php echo $field['pid']; ?>|<?php echo $field['price']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought about giving two values to the checkbox. I like this approach. And also it helps me to get where I want to. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Too bad I cannot up-vote your answer, as I am below 15 reputation :)